# How can I run multiple commands which have & in one command line?

Tags: command-line, bash

I've encountered a headache problem.

I want to execute mulitple commands in background, so I want to start them in bash one by one.
It's easy to start one command in linux shell in background, just like this:

```
myCommand &
```

It's also easy to start multiple commands, just like this:

```
myCommand1 && myCommand2
```

or

```
myCommand1 ; myCommand2
```

But if I want to run multiple commands in background, I tried the following command format, but failed:

```
myCommand1 & && myCommand2 &
```

or

```
myCommand1 & ; myCommand2 &
```

Both formats fail. How can I run multiple commands which have `&` in one command line?

Comment: Put them in a script and run the script in the background

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612371/how-do-i-run-multiple-background-commands-in-bash-in-a-single-line

Comment: Panther, it seems using () could help fix this issue much easier than using a script. Let's try to make full use of the features provided by the shell itself firstly, instead of composing what we want by ourselves. But of course, using script also could fix this issue. Thanks anyway.

Comment: What if I want to run a 'tail -F <file1> > <file2>' followed by 'jobs -l', which is again followed by 'disown -h %1'

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use ().

If you want to run them sequentially:

```
(myCommand1; myCommand2) &
```

or

```
(myCommand1 &) && (myCommand2 &)
```

If you want them to run parallel:

```
myCommand1 & myCommand2 &
```

---

In bash you can also use this (space behind the { and the ; are mandatory):

```
{ myCommand1 && myCommand2; } &
```

Comment: `(myCommand1 &) && (myCommand2 &)` will run `myCommand2` even if `myCommand1` failed.

Comment: () could help bash to distinguish the & and &&. So just use () to seperate the execution unit when we want to use the & and && togather.

Comment: What is the difference between `{}` and `()`?

Comment: @ManuelJordan {} you can use in bash () in more shells

Answer (score 20):

I suppose you want this:

```bsh
myCommand1 & myCommand2 &
```

This starts `myCommand1` and sends it to the background as it's followed by ampersand, then immediately starts `myCommand2` and sends also this to the background, therefore releasing the shell again.

## Lists

For better understanding you may substitute *pipeline* by *command* here.

> A  list  is a sequence of one or more pipelines separated by one of
>   the    operators **;**, **&**, **&&**, or **||**, and optionally terminated by one of
>   **;**, **&**, or    .
>
> If  a  command  is  terminated  by  the  control  operator **&**, the
>   shell    executes the command in the background in a subshell.  The 
>   shell  does    not  wait  for  the  command  to  finish,  and  the
>   return status is 0.    Commands separated by a **;** are executed
>   sequentially;  the  shell  waits    for  each  command to terminate in
>   turn.  The return status is the exit    status of the last command
>   executed.
>
> AND and OR lists are sequences of one or more  pipelines  separated
>   by    the  **&&**  and  **||** control operators, respectively.
>   <sub>Source: [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/bash.1.html)</sub>

Let's break that down into examples. You can build a list by combining commands and separating them with one of these: `; & && ||`:

```bsh
command1 ; command2  # runs sequentially
command1 && command2 # runs sequentially, runs command2 only if command1 succeeds
command1 || command2 # runs sequentially, runs command2 only if command1 fails
command1 & command2  # runs simultaneously
```

You can terminate lists with one of these: `; & <newline>`.
Normally you execute a command or a list by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, that equals `<newline>`. The semicolon `;` serves the very same purpose especially in scripts. Ampersand `&` however starts the command(s) in a subshell in the background, immediately releasing the shell.

You can use round `()` or curly brackets `{}` to further group lists, the difference being that round brackets spawn a subshell and curly ones don't. Curly brackets need a space after the first and a semicolon or a newline before the closing bracket. For example:

```bsh
# if c1 succeeds start a shell in the background
# and run c2 and c3 sequentially inside it
c1 && ( c2 ; c3 ) & 
# run c1 and if it succeeds c2 sequentially as a group command
# if c1 or c2 fail run c3 in the background
{ c1 && c2 ;} || c3 &
```

This can get quite complicated, if you're unsure use `true` and `false` to test whether the construction works as expected:

```bsh
$ { true && true ;} || echo 2
$ { true && false ;} || echo 2
2
```

## Job Control

The `jobs` command displays a list of the background jobs that are running or have recently been finished in the current shell. There are a number of keyboard shortcuts and commands for job control:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> types the *suspend* character that causes the process currently running in the foreground to be stopped, it is not terminated, but remains in the `jobs` list
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> types the *delayed suspend* character that causes the process currently running in the foreground to be stopped when it attempts to read input from the terminal
- `fg` = `%` brings a process into the foreground starting it if necessary, you can specify the process as follows:

  ```bsh
   %       # last process in the jobs list
   %1      # 1st process in the jobs list
   %abc    # process beginning with the string “abc”
   %?abc   # process containing the string “abc” anywhere
  ```
- `bg` = `%&` takes a process into the background starting it if necessary:

  ```bsh
   %&      # last process in the jobs list
   %1&     # 1st process in the jobs list
   %abc&   # process beginning with the string “abc”
   %?abc&  # process containing the string “abc” anywhere
  ```
- `wait` waits for a background process to be finished and returns its termination status:

  ```bsh
   wait %1 # 1st process in the jobs list
  ```

  Imagine you started a lengthy process (`jobs` reveals it's number 3) and then realize you want the computer to be suspended when it finishes, plus `echo` a message if the process didn't succeed:

  ```bsh
   wait %3 || echo failed ; systemctl suspend
  ```